# Google Chrome: Vertical scrollbar disappears on some web pages, maybe due to a strange toolbar

Tags: html, google-chrome

One of my customers have trouble viewing some of the pages on our website. Specifically it is the vertical scrollbar, that disappears on some pages.

She is using Google Chrome, and as the following screenshots will show, Chrome also has a strange toolbar.

On this first image, there are no problem with scrolling

http://i45.tinypic.com/3444bqe.png

On the next, the scrollbar has disappeared although there is plenty of content on the page.

http://i47.tinypic.com/125qdlv.png

I have tried to reproduce the error on my own machine with the same Chrome version, but it was not possible. So I suspect the strange toolbar to be the culprit.

Does anybody know which extension gives this bar?

Comment: Turn off all of the extensions and check.

Comment: I would like to, but it is a customer without any it-knowledge whatsoever. And she is located at the other end of the country. I will try with TeamViewer if no one comes up with an answer, but I suspect, that many customers have this problem, if it is caused by this extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turning the scrollbar always on did the trick for me:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: what if this doesn't work, even if overflow-y: scroll; is on body and not overwritten by anything?

Comment: Not good for the case when ```body``` height is not greater than window height because vertical scrollbar will be displayed always with this style

Answer (score 6):

I fixed my missing scroll bar issue by turning off "Use hardware acceleration when available" It's in chrome://settings/system

Answer (score 5):

Disabling extensions solved my problem, thanks! Here's an additional suggestion. 
To "disable" your extensions quickly and temporarily, just **open a new Incognito window** in Chrome.

```
Menu -> "New incognito window"
```

OR

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Cheers!
Josh

Comment: Also it's necessary to ensure that no extension is set up to be enabled in incognito mode.

Answer (score 3):

I did the same thing that @Carey Pico did and it worked
**disabling extensions**.
 I first ran into this missing right scroll bar problem when opening Yahoo news pages today. I disabled all extensions 
`(access tools --> extensions)` 
and got back my right scroll bar where it should be.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this situation where my "yahoo finance" page lost its scroll bar (after reinstalling Chrome).  I only had one remaining extension left running (one I trusted).  It was AVG Secure Search (I used AVG antivirus).  I disabled it and the scroll bar appeared the next time I opened Yahoo Finance.  Interestingly, I had left the old, missing scroll bar page open.  It was unaffected.

So, AVG Secure Search extension interferes with yahoo products.

Answer (score 0):

I verified what extensions I had running, and the one that caused issues was my Avira Safebrowsing extension - disabled the extension and all good.

Answer (score 0):

For me the source of the problem was Ghostery extension. After installing "Ghostery fixer" extension scrollbar reappeared.