# Scrollbars disappear after using blueimp lightbox

Tags: image, scrollbar, gallery, blueimp

I found blueimp image gallery and wanted to use it with bootstrap.
I stumbled over a problem and reduced everything to bare blueimp script.
When I click on an image and the lightbox opens and I swipe through the images or use the arrow to slide through the images every now and then but not always the scrollbars disappear. I tried to reduce the code as far as possible:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="blueimp">
        <div>
          <div>
            <a href="/core/5t/500/image_jpg/1500_1500/0409_57416_aw01_iso_kl.jpg" title="First Title" data-gallery>
              <img src="/core/5t/500/image_jpg/425_425/0409_57416_aw01_iso_kl.jpg" width="425" height="425" alt="First Title">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/core/5t/500/image_jpg/1500_1500/0409_57416_aw02_iso_kl.jpg" title="Second Title" data-gallery>
              <img src="/core/5t/500/image_jpg/160_160/0409_57416_aw02_iso_kl.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Second Title">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
          <div>
            <a href="/core/5t/500/image_jpg/1500_1500/0409_57421_aw01_iso_kl.jpg" title="Third Title" data-gallery>
            <img src="/core/5t/500/image_jpg/160_160/0409_57421_aw01_iso_kl.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Third Title">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
 <div class="slides"></div>
 <h3 class="title"></h3>
 <a class="prev">‹</a>
 <a class="next">›</a>
 <a class="close">×</a>
  <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/udx_lib/blueimp-gallery/2.16.0/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<script src="/udx_lib/jquery/1.11.3/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/udx_lib/blueimp-gallery/2.16.0/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById('blueimp').onclick = function (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
  links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
  blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
</script>
```

I found this [post about overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560797/google-chrome-vertical-scrollbar-disappears-on-some-web-pages-maybe-due-to-a-s)
and also information about hidePageScrollbars. But neither

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

nor

```
options = {index: link, event: event, hidePageScrollbars: false},
```

does make any difference. Sometimes loading the lightbox once more and closing it lets the scrollbar reappear. Reloading the page leads to a site showing the scrollbar.

The error could be produced on Chrome and Firefox, I did not use and test IE.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Cheers

Derion

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this?

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery" data-hide-page-scrollbars="false">
```

or alternatively via CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, what worked for me was:

```
html,
body{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```